# Lattice deformation (bending) - not having any luck

Tags: lattice

I've looked at a few tutorials and done everything according to them but can't get the object in the lattice to deform.
- Created lattice, scaled, added additional area in lattice, and put object in center.
- Selected object, added lattice modifier and attached it to lattice.
- Subdivided object several different ways numerous times.

Each time I alter the lattice, it does nothing to the object. What am I doing wrong? Trying to get the mouthpiece to curve around the mask better.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbEDA.gif

Comment: You can’t modify your mesh once you use lattice

Answer (score 2):

Add lattice modifier and subdivide if needed. Select the mesh on which lattice modifier you need to apply. Go to modifier tab in the lattice modifier in the object mode select lattice or with dropper select the lattice. Now select the lattice in the 3d view. Go to edit mode and with the verts selected move it where your satisfied.

[image]